# Bootstrap5 Modal Uncaught TypeError: 'querySelector' called on an object that does not implement interface Element

Tags: bootstrap-5

i want to use a modal so like in the docu i trie it in this way

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Launch static backdrop modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On click at the button i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: 'querySelector' called on an object that does not implement interface Element"

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data-bs-target` and your modal's `id` should be identical, changing `data-bs-target` value to `#exampleModal` should fix your problem.

Comment: Adding the correct `id` did not fix my problem, but adding `div class=modal-dialog>` fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error in Bootstrap 5 when I had `data-bs-target` set to the right modal ID, but the modal itself wasn't formatted correctly. To work properly the `modal` parent class has to include at least a `modal-dialog` child element.

Comment: This helped me, so plus one, the html must be `<div class=modal><div class=modal-dialog><div class=modal-header>..</div></div></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Removing the "`data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop`" Part of the button solved the problem. I dont know what or why it came up, but now it works for me.

Comment: Your answer seems wrong. You should show the working code. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I removed "data-bs-target" and worked for me, my code

Button, you have to assign it an id:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button id="test" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("test"));

myModal.toggle();
```

Comment: Where does the `bootstrap` in `new bootstrap..` come from? Your example is not valid.

Comment: @Timo , bootstrap cam from node_module directory.

it seems his project uses external JS and does not use a CDN style like some.
this approach is better sine its IDE know and can help you with the syntax and you can benefit from tree shaking if u using a modular style